# dart - What is the naming convention for templates and macro in comments

Tags: flutter, dart, dartdoc

Dart has a [dartdoc](https://pub.dev/packages/dartdoc) documentation syntax with `{@template}` and `{@macro}`. I was wondering if there was a naming convention for it.
In the [doc](https://pub.dev/packages/dartdoc), they only give the `{@template template_name}` example which is in `snake_case`.

For now, I'm naming my templates like this:

`{@template project_name.class_name.method_name}` (`snake_case` separated with `.`).

For example for the project `project_name`:

File `class_name.dart`

```dart
/// {@template project_name.class_name}
/// ...
/// {@endtemplate}
class ClassName {
  /// {@template project_name.class_name.method_name}
  /// ...
  /// {@endtemplate}
  void methodName() {}
}
```

I was wondering if there was already some conventions for those template names?